# Spring Test MVC : Testing controller that redirects to another controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I am attempting to use Spring Test MVC to test a controller method.

I have a controller that handles a form submission and persists a new entry to the db.

If the method is successful the controller performs a redirect to another controller (the second controller retrieves the entity's ID from a path variable, retrieves it from the DB, populates model attributes and displays the details page for the newly persisted entity).

In the first controller no attributes are added onto the Model or the RedirectAttributes.

This is the controller method I am attempting to test:

```
@RequestMapping("/save/{templateId}/{configParameterId}")
public String saveGatewayPPTPConfigParameter(@PathVariable Long templateId, @PathVariable Long configParameterId, @Valid GatewayPPTPConfigParameterForm configParameterForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request,
        RedirectAttributes flash, Model model)  {
...
...
... Code omitted
...
    return "redirect:/admin/gateway/config/template/details" + newTemplate.getId()+ "#tab_3";
    }
```

If this method executes successfully then the following code in the 2nd controller would populate the model with some attributes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details/{templateId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewConfigTemplateDetails(@PathVariable Long templateId, Model model) throws IOException, ServletException, WifireAdminSessionException, WifireAdminException {

....
....
....Code ommited
....
....

    model.addAttribute("configTemplate", gatewayConfig);

    return "/admin/gateway/config/template/details";
}
```

Consider this snippet from my test:

```
mvc.perform(
            post("/admin/gateway/config/parameter/save/{templateId}/{configParameterId}", 6 , 8)
                                    .param("name", "name")
                                    .param("value", "value")
                                    .param("typeId", "3")
                                    .param("parameterId", "2")
                                    .param("readOnly", "false"))

            .andDo(
                    MockMvcResultHandlers.print()
            )
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/admin/gateway/config/template/details/"+mapping.getId()+"#tab_3"));
```

This test passes but if I add:

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("configTemplate", hasProperty("id",is(4l))))
```

It fails because the `configTemplate` model attribute is null.

If the second controller had executed successfully then the `configTemplate` would be populated. Why is it that the `expectedView` is correct but the second controller did not seem to execute?

Comment: Can you add more information? like the controllers code, not the complete code but the method definition, the model changes and the return of the method with their views.

Comment: I added the information you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I'm assuming this:

You have this path associate with controllers

```
/admin/gateway/config/parameter/
```

and this path assosiated with views

```
/admin/gateway/config/template/
```

If this is true, you're redirecting to a view

```
return "redirect:/admin/gateway/config/template/details" + newTemplate.getId()+ "#tab_3";
```

And the second controller its never executed, this is because the resulting view that you're redirecting it's never executed. So if you check the expectedview is correct but the controller is never executed.

Comment: But I still seem to get thymeleaf exceptions on null model attributes.

So for the moment I am just focusing on testing the 1st controller then look at the 2nd controller at a lager stage.